# SonataUserBundle : try to go /profile => route "sonata_customer_addresses" does not exist

Tags: symfony, routes, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I can't figured out why I have this error.

Herewith more informations abour my problem :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sonata_customer_addresses" as such route does not exist.") in SonataUserBundle:Profile:action.html.twig at line 27.
```

to implement my own User Class.

I use Symfony 2.4 with dev-master SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle. I try

you can find my config.yml :

```
    sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm
    profile:
        # Profile show page is a dashboard as in SonataAdminBundle
        dashboard:
            blocks:
                - { position: left, type: sonata.block.service.text, settings: { content: "<h2>Welcome!</h2> This is a sample user profile dashboard, feel free to override it in the configuration! Want to make this text dynamic? For instance display the user's name? Create a dedicated block and edit the configuration!"} }
                - { position: left, type: sonata.order.block.recent_orders, settings: { title: Recent Orders, number: 5, mode: public }}
                - { position: right, type: sonata.timeline.block.timeline, settings: { max_per_page: 15 }}
                - { position: right, type: sonata.news.block.recent_posts, settings: { title: Recent Posts, number: 5, mode: public }}
                - { position: right, type: sonata.news.block.recent_comments, settings: { title: Recent Comments, number: 5, mode: public }}
        # Customize user portal menu by setting links
        menu:
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_show', label: 'sonata_profile_title', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit', label: 'link_edit_profile', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_customer_addresses', label: 'link_list_addresses', domain: 'SonataCustomerBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit_authentication', label: 'link_edit_authentication', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
            - { route: 'sonata_order_index', label: 'order_list', domain: 'SonataOrderBundle'}

#sonata_admin:
#    templates:
#        dashboard: SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig

sonata_admin:
    title:      Admin Panel
    title_logo: /bundles/sonataadmin/logo_title.png
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig
        ajax:    SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig

        # default actions templates, should extend a global templates
        list:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        show:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig
        edit:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            # display a dashboard block
            - { position: left, type: sonata.admin.block.admin_list }


sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts:   [admin]

        #sonata.admin_doctrine_orm.block.audit:
        #    contexts:   [admin]
        sonata.user.block.menu:
        sonata.user.block.account:
        sonata.block.service.text:
        sonata.block.service.action:
        sonata.block.service.rss:

sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    # default value is null, so doctrine uses the value defined in the configuration
    entity_manager: ~
    templates:
        form:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:form_admin_fields.html.twig
        filter:
            - SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig
        types:
            list:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig
                identifier: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig

            show:
                array:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_array.html.twig
                boolean:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_boolean.html.twig
                date:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_date.html.twig
                time:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_time.html.twig
                datetime:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_datetime.html.twig
                text:       SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                trans:      SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_trans.html.twig
                string:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                smallint:   SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                bigint:     SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                integer:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig
                decimal:    SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_show_field.html.twig


# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\User
    group:
        group_class:   MyProject\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager                   

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
```

and my routing.yml here :

```
    sonata_user_security:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_security_1.xml"

sonata_user_resetting:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_resetting_1.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

sonata_user_profile:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_profile_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user_register:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_registration_1.xml"
    prefix: /register

sonata_user_change_password:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_change_password_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

EDIT 1:

```
[router] Current routes
 Name                                     Method   Scheme Host Path                                               
 _assetic_bootstrap_css                   ANY      ANY    ANY  /assetic/bootstrap_css.less                        
 _assetic_bootstrap_css_0                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /assetic/bootstrap_css_bootstrap_1.less            
 _assetic_jquery                          ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/jquery.js                                      
 _assetic_jquery_0                        ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/jquery_jquery-2.1.1_1.js                       
 _assetic_bootstrap_js                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap.js                                   
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_0                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_transition_1.js                      
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_1                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_alert_2.js                           
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_2                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_button_3.js                          
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_3                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_carousel_4.js                        
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_4                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_collapse_5.js                        
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_5                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_dropdown_6.js                        
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_6                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_modal_7.js                           
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_7                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_tooltip_8.js                         
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_8                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_popover_9.js                         
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_9                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_scrollspy_10.js                      
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_10                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_tab_11.js                            
 _assetic_bootstrap_js_11                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/bootstrap_affix_12.js                          
 _assetic_a56fa94                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/a56fa94.js                                     
 _assetic_a56fa94_0                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/a56fa94_part_1.js                              
 _assetic_a56fa94_1                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/a56fa94_part_2.js                              
 _assetic_65cec74                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /css/65cec74.css                                   
 _wdt                                     ANY      ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}                                      
 _profiler_home                           ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/                                        
 _profiler_search                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search                                  
 _profiler_search_bar                     ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar                              
 _profiler_purge                          ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge                                   
 _profiler_info                           ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}                            
 _profiler_import                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/import                                  
 _profiler_export                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/export/{token}.txt                      
 _profiler_phpinfo                        ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo                                 
 _profiler_search_results                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results                  
 _profiler                                ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}                                 
 _profiler_router                         ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router                          
 _profiler_exception                      ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception                       
 _profiler_exception_css                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css                   
 _configurator_home                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /_configurator/                                    
 _configurator_step                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}                        
 _configurator_final                      ANY      ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final                               
 fos_user_security_login                  ANY      ANY    ANY  /login                                             
 fos_user_security_check                  POST     ANY    ANY  /login_check                                       
 fos_user_security_logout                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /logout                                            
 sonata_user_security_login               ANY      ANY    ANY  /login                                             
 sonata_user_security_check               POST     ANY    ANY  /login_check                                       
 sonata_user_security_logout              ANY      ANY    ANY  /logout                                            
 fos_user_resetting_request               GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/request                                 
 fos_user_resetting_send_email            POST     ANY    ANY  /resetting/send-email                              
 fos_user_resetting_check_email           GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/check-email                             
 fos_user_resetting_reset                 GET|POST ANY    ANY  /resetting/reset/{token}                           
 sonata_user_resetting_request            GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/request                                 
 sonata_user_resetting_send_email         POST     ANY    ANY  /resetting/send-email                              
 sonata_user_resetting_check_email        GET      ANY    ANY  /resetting/check-email                             
 sonata_user_resetting_reset              GET|POST ANY    ANY  /resetting/reset/{token}                           
 fos_user_profile_show                    GET      ANY    ANY  /profile/                                          
 fos_user_profile_edit_authentication     ANY      ANY    ANY  /profile/edit-authentication                       
 fos_user_profile_edit                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /profile/edit-profile                              
 sonata_user_profile_show                 GET      ANY    ANY  /profile/                                          
 sonata_user_profile_edit_authentication  ANY      ANY    ANY  /profile/edit-authentication                       
 sonata_user_profile_edit                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /profile/edit-profile                              
 fos_user_registration_register           ANY      ANY    ANY  /register/                                         
 fos_user_registration_check_email        GET      ANY    ANY  /register/check-email                              
 fos_user_registration_confirm            GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirm/{token}                          
 fos_user_registration_confirmed          GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirmed                                
 sonata_user_registration_register        ANY      ANY    ANY  /register/                                         
 sonata_user_registration_check_email     GET      ANY    ANY  /register/check-email                              
 sonata_user_registration_confirm         GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirm/{token}                          
 sonata_user_registration_confirmed       GET      ANY    ANY  /register/confirmed                                
 fos_user_change_password                 GET|POST ANY    ANY  /profile/change-password                           
 sonata_user_change_password              GET|POST ANY    ANY  /profile/change-password                           
 sonata_user_admin_security_login         ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/login                                       
 sonata_user_admin_security_check         ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/login_check                                 
 sonata_user_admin_security_logout        ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/logout                                      
 sonata_admin_redirect                    ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/                                            
 sonata_admin_dashboard                   ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/dashboard                                   
 sonata_admin_retrieve_form_element       ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/core/get-form-field-element                 
 sonata_admin_append_form_element         ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/core/append-form-field-element              
 sonata_admin_short_object_information    ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/core/get-short-object-description.{_format} 
 sonata_admin_set_object_field_value      ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/core/set-object-field-value                 
 sonata_admin_search                      ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/search                                      
 sonata_admin_retrieve_autocomplete_items ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/core/get-autocomplete-items                 
 admin_sonata_user_user_list              ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/list                       
 admin_sonata_user_user_create            ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/create                     
 admin_sonata_user_user_batch             ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/batch                      
 admin_sonata_user_user_edit              ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/{id}/edit                  
 admin_sonata_user_user_delete            ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/{id}/delete                
 admin_sonata_user_user_show              ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/{id}/show                  
 admin_sonata_user_user_export            ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/user/export                     
 admin_sonata_user_group_list             ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/list                      
 admin_sonata_user_group_create           ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/create                    
 admin_sonata_user_group_batch            ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/batch                     
 admin_sonata_user_group_edit             ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/{id}/edit                 
 admin_sonata_user_group_delete           ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/{id}/delete               
 admin_sonata_user_group_show             ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/{id}/show                 
 admin_sonata_user_group_export           ANY      ANY    ANY  /admin/sonata/user/group/export                    
 myproject_user_default_index            ANY      ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}                                      
 myproject_comment_default_index         ANY      ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}                                      
 myproject_provider_default_index        ANY      ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}                                      
 myproject_provider_providersearch_index ANY      ANY    ANY  /ProviderSearch                                    
 myproject_service_default_index         ANY      ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}                                      
 myproject_geo_default_index             ANY      ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}                                      
 myproject_schedule_default_index        ANY      ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}                                      
 myproject_coupon_couponsearch_index     ANY      ANY    ANY  /couponSearch                                      
 my_filter                                ANY      ANY    ANY  /filter/                                           
 myproject_coupon_default_index          ANY      ANY    ANY  /coupon                                            
 myproject_association_search            ANY      ANY    ANY  /associationSearch                                 
 myproject_association_search_result     ANY      ANY    ANY  /associationSearch/result                          
 myproject_association_search_show       ANY      ANY    ANY  /association/{slug}                                
 myproject_contact                       ANY      ANY    ANY  /contact                                           
 myproject_core_homepage                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /                                                  
 myproject_city_typeahead                ANY      ANY    ANY  /autocompleteCity                                  
 myproject_assoName_typeahead            ANY      ANY    ANY  /autocompleteAssoName                              
 myproject_providerName_typeahead        ANY      ANY    ANY  /autocompleteProviderName                          
 myproject_core_static                   ANY      ANY    ANY  /{page}                                            
 myproject_coupon                        ANY      ANY    ANY  /coupon                                            
 myproject_coupon_search                 ANY      ANY    ANY  /couponSearch                                      
 myproject_coupon_search_result          ANY      ANY    ANY  /couponSearch/result                               
 myproject_provider_search_show          ANY      ANY    ANY  /provider/{slug}                                   
 fos_js_routing_js                        ANY      ANY    ANY  /js/routing.{_format}
```

Comment: First check to see if the if the router has loaded your route `app/console router:debug --env=prod` (make sure to clear the cache before doing this)

Comment: Apparently, there is no sonata_customer_addresses

I can't find any documentation about this route in sonata-project

Comment: Where are you getting things like `SonataCustomerBundle` and `sonata_customer_addresses` from? is there a bundle with instructions to add these?

Comment: It was in configuration documentation.

I try to remove `- { route: 'sonata_customer_addresses', label: 'link_list_addresses', domain: 'SonataCustomerBundle'}`
and `- { route: 'sonata_order_index', label: 'order_list', domain: 'SonataOrderBundle'}` because it's two bundle I don't have and I am facing a new error about `sonata.order.block.recent_orders`

I don't know why the SonataUserBundle try to use SonataECommerce, and I don't know how to avoid the use of this bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got a dashboard by removing all in sonata_user like this :

```
sonata_user:
    security_acl:           true
    manager_type: orm
```

I try to get a Dashboard like in this documentation : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/user_dashboard.html without success.

I have a blank page now, I will do all dashboard on my own,I can't see other way...

Answer (score 0):

You should copy paste the code from the inatallation documentation into config.yml (like me).
Remove the lines with sonata_customer and sonata_order.

```
profile:
    # Profile show page is a dashboard as in SonataAdminBundle
    dashboard:
        blocks:
            - { position: left, type: sonata.block.service.text, settings: { content: "<h2>Welcome!</h2> This is a sample user profile dashboard, feel free to override it in the configuration! Want to make this text dynamic? For instance display the user's name? Create a dedicated block and edit the configuration!"} }
            - { position: left, type: sonata.order.block.recent_orders, settings: { title: Recent Orders, number: 5, mode: public }}
            - { position: right, type: sonata.timeline.block.timeline, settings: { max_per_page: 15 }}
            - { position: right, type: sonata.news.block.recent_posts, settings: { title: Recent Posts, number: 5, mode: public }}
            - { position: right, type: sonata.news.block.recent_comments, settings: { title: Recent Comments, number: 5, mode: public }}
    # Customize user portal menu by setting links
    menu:
        - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_show', label: 'sonata_profile_title', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
        - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit', label: 'link_edit_profile', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
        - { route: 'sonata_customer_addresses', label: 'link_list_addresses', domain: 'SonataCustomerBundle'}
        - { route: 'sonata_user_profile_edit_authentication', label: 'link_edit_authentication', domain: 'SonataUserBundle'}
        - { route: 'sonata_order_index', label: 'order_list', domain: 'SonataOrderBundle'}
```